# How to edit Blenderkit files

Tags: edit-mode, blenderkit

I just enabled the Blenderkit addon but cannot seem to figure out how to edit the objects. I looked in this reddit thread and amazingly none of the solutions worked for me. https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/hizn42/i_downloaded_this_model_from_blenderkit_and_i/
Making it a single user object, data, and materials did not work.
I do not see any option to append when adding a model form the Blenderkit asset bar (I even tried saving it and appending the object in another instance of Blender and it still would not let me edit it).
And when I right click I do not see an option to make local on outliner collection.
I am using Blender 2.83 if that makes a difference but can use 2.9 if need be.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import settings from *"link"* to *"append"*:

[image]

BlenderKits creates blend file in your disk, by the way.

Comment: I didn't see where this menu was at at first, but it is the expendable menu on the right hand side of the screen that I had mistakenly collapse with the N key. Got it.